# How to select only certain fields with Quarkus Panache?

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-panache

`Quarkus` simplifies Hibernate ORM mappings with `Panache`.

Here is an example of my `entity` and `PanacheRepository`:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate birth;
    private Status status;
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class PersonRepository implements PanacheRepository<Person> {

   // example
   public Person findByName(String name){
       return find("name", name).firstResult();
   }


   // ! and this is what I tried, but it's not possible to do it this way
   // all the methods return Person or something of type Person like List<Person>
   // so basically this won't even compile
   public List<String> findAllLastNames() {
       return this.find("select p.lastName from Person p").list();
   }

}
```

All the guides explain how to write different queries, but is not clear how to select only certain attributes.

If I don't need the whole `Person` object, but rather the `lastName` of all persons in my DB?

Is it possible to select only certain attributes with `Quarkus Panache`?

Comment: This is a good question. I have the same issue including returning aggregates like SUM() in select

Comment: @Aiden you can vote it up if you think it is useful:)

Comment: Quarkus has introduced projection which will use a custom pojo to dynamically identify the required columns to use in query. See documentation [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#query-projection)

Comment: @aksappy Thank you :) I think this comment is helpful, but if you have time I think it might be valuable to add it as an answer with a little details - because it looks like current approved answer is not valid anymore. Also you can vote up this question if you think it might be useful for other people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [@aksappy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2042457/aksappy) said, this feature was added and it's documentation is available [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#query-projection).

Answer (score 8):

This is currently not possible, you can subscribe to this issue regarding projection for Hibernate with Panache: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6261

Don't hesistate to vote for it (+1 reaction) and provides feedback.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Query Parameters ->

```
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("fisrtName", fisrtName);
    params.put("lastName", lastName);

    final List<String> enetityList = Person.list("fisrtName= :fisrtName and lastName= :lastName", params);
```

reference - https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache